# Is it possible to have offline access in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

Can it be possible to have access to content in SharePoint 2010 when an internet connection is not available, i.e. offline access which will be based on permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of Microsoft SharePoint Workspace 2010, the new name for Microsoft Office Groove,  is a client application (included with Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010) for SharePoint Server 2010 and SharePoint Foundation 2010. It provides offline access to SharePoint documents and lists from desktop and enables real-time synchronization of content in desktop with that in the SharePoint. When you are connected to the SharePoint server, all content updates on the server and in the workspace are automatically synchronized. When you are not connected, changes you make in the workspace are cached locally. The next time you connect to the SharePoint server, all changes are automatically synchronized.

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2011/04/13/using-sharepoint-workspace-2010.aspx)

Also have a look at the below link,

[SharePoint Workspace 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2011/05/31/sharepoint-workspace-2010-offline-working-capabilities.aspx)